# Why is my 1st code images behaving differently compared to my 2nd code background-images despite using the same width unit @ 30%?

Tags: html, css

**1st Code:**

https://jsfiddle.net/dmbgc4qz/1/

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60vh;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 2.5rem 1.5rem 0;
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648070201547-9d6ef53d3a51?ixlib=rb- 
    1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1332&q=80");
    text-align: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

- The images from this code which are background-images gets progressively thinner when I change the size of the screen and it eventually turn to 1 image as the size of the screen gets smaller.

**2nd Code:**

https://jsfiddle.net/dmbgc4qz/2/

```
img {
    width: 30%;
}
```

- The images from this code which are html  do not get progressively thinner and remain as triplet per line even when the size of the screen is altered.

Can anybody please explain this phenomenon to me? Why is the image behaving so differently despite same width unit provided? Is it because of the display property?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you didn't specify the `margin` for the `img` so if you add this `margin: 2.5rem 1.5rem 0;` it will act similarly to the first one

```css
img {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 2.5rem 1.5rem 0;
    height:60vh;
    object-fit:cover;
    object-position:center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648070201547-9d6ef53d3a51?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1332&q=80" alt="">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648070201547-9d6ef53d3a51?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1332&q=80" alt="">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648070201547-9d6ef53d3a51?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1332&q=80" alt="">
    
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648070201547-9d6ef53d3a51?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1332&q=80" alt="">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648070201547-9d6ef53d3a51?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1332&q=80" alt="">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648070201547-9d6ef53d3a51?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1332&q=80" alt="">

    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648070201547-9d6ef53d3a51?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1332&q=80" alt="">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648070201547-9d6ef53d3a51?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1332&q=80" alt="">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648070201547-9d6ef53d3a51?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1332&q=80" alt="">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Even if I add the margin, the images will scale accordingly and can be seen in its entirety when I shrink the screen size unlike the images from code 1 which will get narrower as it shrink the screen.

Comment: oh i understand now, yeah for that you need to specify the `height` ,`object-fit` and `object-position` because `img` has different properties from `div` I will update my answer